# How to add DatePicker dynamically under UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I'm not sure it can be able to add DatePicker dynamically under UITextField when tapped on. If possible, help me to show sample code for that.

Comment: @PravinTate sample code?

Comment: have you tried it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**on click event set on text field**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
}
```

**set text field edition false**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    return NO;
}
```

**Method when clickd on text filed**

```
 -(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
    {
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
         picker1   = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x-40, textField.frame.origin.y+textField.frame.size.height, textField.frame.size.width, 200)];
        [picker1 setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
        picker1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [picker1 addTarget:self action:@selector(startDateSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.view addSubview:picker1];
    }
```

**when date value changed this method is called**

```
-(IBAction)startDateSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",picker1.date);
    [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker1.date
            ]];
}
```

I hope it will help you! :)